# Is a 60A subpanel adequate for my needs?

Tags: electrical, wiring, circuit-breaker, subpanel

I have a 200 amp service for main panel in the house. I want to add a subpanel in the barn 125 feet away, buried. I currently have a 10/2 cable going to a 20 amp panel and I keep blowing the breaker in the house after I added a simple blow up spa (120V) with heat. I have a Hayward 2 pump for my inground pool. When I run the shop vac or a combination of the 3, I trip the main breaker in the main panel which is 20 amps.

Will a 60 amp breaker in the main, and 6 gauge 4 wire in conduit be enough to power all 3, plus a 5k btu a/c or heater at 120V? I have done electrical work before and am familiar with most of it. I just need help with the math and wire selection.

Thank you.

Comment: Use 2-2-2-4 aluminum, (or 2-2-2 + a 10AWG copper ground, or in metallic conduit with no ground wire since the conduit is ground) rather than spending too much money on 6 AWG copper wires or cable.

Comment: It would be nice to say just go ahead and add the 60 amps, but.  Without knowing what you use the panel for, it might be too much.  With thinking of adding 60 amp breaker it is recommended(probably required) to do a load calculation(google) for your panel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Want to add sub-panel in my barn - 115v, 60amp?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/213375/want-to-add-sub-panel-in-my-barn-115v-60amp) It's been asked [a hundred times before](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adiy.stackexchange.com+what+size+subpanel+for+barn&rlz=1), with slight variation.